# On how many instances is my Azure WebApi running

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to implement [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr) hubs on my REST service (ASP.NET Web Api) hosted on azure. I've been reading some common stuff related to SignalR and I came to this one that it is server bound. You can check [here](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://youtu.be/us-Q3do-N7M?t%3D47m20s&sa=D&ust=1504098969557000&usg=AFQjCNH85QWkHgUs1Niir3GeBYDt1EcXHg). Which means that in order to be able to scale it on multiple server instancs I have to do some additional stuff. So, then, I started to ask myself ***"How many instances do I currently have running of my REST service on Azure? How do I know that?"***

So, what I did was - I navigated to azure portal and opened my service > Process explorer
[image]

Does that mean than my web app scales automatically and I currently have 2 instances of my web api runing? I think it clearly says that there's currently only one instaces of it running 2 processes but how do I know if it will scale some time in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your photo shows your app process and Kudu, which is a management interface you can access at https://yourappname.scm.azurewebsites.net.

You can see the instance count in your app's App Service Plan. If it is on Free or Shared, there can only be one. If it is Basic/Standard/Premium, it is one by default. If you haven't setup auto-scale, it won't scale to more than 1 instance unless you tell it to.

Comment: I am running it on a Free plan. So, I believe it is a single instance. Thanks a lot for the info.

Comment: Yeah, so on Free plan your app is running on shared infrastructure. You actually don't have any instances. It is just running on some shared one :) But yeah, single instance. You can read about the pricing tiers here: https://blog.siliconvalve.com/2016/05/12/understanding-azure-app-service-plans-and-pricing/